bought a token that is unsellable, but I can see that on Etherscan that few accounts are selling the same. Is there a way I can sell this token
I bought this token 'Monad' on uniswap. It seems to be all fine but than later realized that this token is unsellable.
I can see that the team are able to sell the token, and so did someone else who I am guessing is part of the scam. if anyone who knows how to deal with issue then pleased le me know and advise the way to sell this token, your help will much appreciated.
here is the contract for "MONAD" https://etherscan.io/address/0x0c2395Acb0268657b0B99441123dac2106915bA2
thanks in advance for reading and your help!

If you traded it on uniswap it means there is a liquidity pool with both liquidities in it. You should be able to trade it back in that pool.

https://app.uniswap.org/explore/tokens/ethereum/0x0c2395acb0268657b0b99441123dac2106915ba2
Try swapping it here

Sorry, but the token looks like a scam contract.
